# Retrieving values from ajax post object

Tags: ajax, post

I have 6 JS objects that each contain three values.

question1 = {testNumber : 51, Answer : 2 , timeComplete : 05:00:00)
question2 = etc etc etc.

then I have one object to hold them all:
var allQuestions = {q1:question1, q2:question2, q3:question3, q4:question4, q5:question5, q6:question6};

I used ajax to send this object to my php page:

$.ajax({

```
 type: 'POST',

 url: allURL, 

 data: {"questions" : JSON.stringify(allQuestions)},


 success: function( resp ){

    $('#allanswers').append( resp );


 },
 error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
    alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
    console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
    console.log( "Status: " + status );
    console.dir( xhr );
},
```

});

now im trying to access these variables server-side:

What am I doing wrong? I realize it may be a nesting issue, but im confused on how to reference these objects/arrays now.

Answer (score 0):

When you send a request to the server in php, you access that information through the $_REQUEST variable (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Try including this in your php code to see exactly what is getting sent to the server:

```
<?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?>
```

Comment: Array ( [questions] => {\"q1\":{\"testNumber\":\"31\",\"Answer\":\"1\",\"timeComplete\":\"16:39:91\"},\"q2\":{\"testNumber\":\"30\",\"Answer\":\"1\",\"timeComplete\":\"16:39:69\"},\"q3\":{\"testNumber\":\"29\",\"Answer\":\"1\",\"timeComplete\":\"16:39:19\"},\"q4\":{\"testNumber\":\"28\",\"Answer\":\"1\",\"timeComplete\":\"16:38:61\"},\"q5\":{\"testNumber\":\"27\",\"Answer\":\"1\",\"timeComplete\":\"16:38:83\"},\"q6\":{\"testNumber\":\"27\",\"Answer\":\"1\",\"timeComplete\":\"16:39:51\"}} )

Comment: so, in my php, if i wanted to retrieve the q2.testnumber, what would my syntax be? i've tried 

$q1_questionID = $questions[1]["testNumber"];

Which obviously doesnt work.

Comment: Perfect!  Looks like the information is getting up there fine.  Now you can just treat that like any other associative array in PHP.

`$_REQUEST['questions']['q1']['testNumber'];`

Comment: im sorry...how would i get the values in each q1, q2..etc

$q1 = $_REQUEST['questions']['q1']['testNumber'];?

Comment: Yes that's correct.  `$q1=$_REQUEST['questions']['q1']['testNumber'];`

Comment: If this solution was helpful to you, would you mind marking my answer as accepted? i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Answer (score 0):

I wasnt able to use this answer. For some reason the array was not accessible. I ended up using regular form to form links. I have to read more on ajax/jquery/php.

Thank you Casey for your attempt.